# Failed to fetch data from localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, fetch-api

I made my first API with NodeJs.

This is what I get if I try to access to the resource from the URL of the browser:

[image]

I succeed to access to posts with Postman.
Now I tried to set a little call with a graphic site, but I wasn't able to fetch the data.

This is the call that I tried in a saga:

```
export const fetchWrapper = async url => {
  var request = new Request({
      url: url,
      method: "GET"
  });
  await fetch(request)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
          result => {
              return result;
          },
          error => {
              return error;
          }
      );
};
```

and this is the saga

```
export function* getPosts() {
    const url = `http://localhost:8080/feed/posts`;
    try {
        const  data  = yield call(fetch(url), {method: 'GET'});
        console.log('data',)
        yield put(getPostsResponse({ data }));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
    }
}
```

and these are the errors that I have in the console:

[image]

[image]

***UPDATE***

As suggested in the comment this is my node code :

controller/feed.js

```
exports.getPosts = (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
        posts: [
            { id: 1, title: "Titolo 1", description: "descrizione 1" },
            { id: 2, title: "Titolo 2", description: "descrizione 2" },
            { id: 3, title: "Titolo 3", description: "descrizione 3" }
        ]
    });
};

exports.createPosts = (req, res, next) => {
    const title = req.body.title;
    const description = req.body.description;

    const ID = 1234;

    res.status(201).json({
        message: "success operation",
        post: {
            id: ID,
            title: title,
            description: description
        }
    });
};
```

route/feed.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const feedController = require("../controllers/feed");

router.get("/post", feedController.getPosts);
router.post("/post", feedController.createPosts);


module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const feedRoute = require('./route/feed');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); //application json
app.use('/feed', feedRoute);
app.listen(8080);
```

***UPDATE***

```
useEffect(() => {
        // getPosts();
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/feed/post")
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => console.log('data', data));
    }, [getPosts]);
```

also tried this, but nothing, I receive the same error.

***Expected behaviour:***

I have to do a successful call to the localhost server.

***Solution***

As @ivani suggested I just enabled the CORS, this is the code the code that I added to app.js. Not the best solution, but now I can see the response.

```
const allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8080"];

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: function(origin, callback) {
            if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
            if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
                var msg =
                    "The CORS policy for this site does not " +
                    "allow access from the specified Origin.";
                return callback(new Error(msg), false);
            }
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: You should try to make a successful call to that endpoint without generator functions (`function*` / `yield`) and without `async await` - when that's working add in the language features that make your program perfomant.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i tried to insert a simple fetch().then() with urls, but i had the same error, do you think that is better if i create a temporary github repo and put it online so everyone can see all of my code ? Or i don't know...the postman screenshot can help you ?

Comment: Have you enabled CORS headers as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)? It seems from the screenshot that you're accessing an endpoint at port 8080 while the app is served from port 3000, which would count as a different origin. Postman doesn't care about that, but requests made from javascript does.

Comment: @Legeo what is the error that you're seeing? Unclear why the `post` request is red - the one that you highlighted and showing the `request` and `response` headers for is not for the `post` request.

Comment: @goto1 i changed the second image, but as you can see the response error is always the same :|

Comment: @ivarni tryin to enable the cors as you say, i will update  :) thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ivani suggested i just enabled the CORS.

I added this to App.js of nodeJs

```
const allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:8080"];

    app.use(
        cors({
            origin: function(origin, callback) {
                if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
                if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
                    var msg =
                        "The CORS policy for this site does not " +
                        "allow access from the specified Origin.";
                    return callback(new Error(msg), false);
                }
                return callback(null, true);
            }
        })
    );
```

Now i can reach the data

[image]

this is the entire App.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const feedRoute = require('./route/feed');
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

const allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8080"];

app.use(
    cors({
        origin: function(origin, callback) {
            if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
            if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
                var msg =
                    "The CORS policy for this site does not " +
                    "allow access from the specified Origin.";
                return callback(new Error(msg), false);
            }
            return callback(null, true);
        }
    })
);

app.use(bodyParser.json()); //application json
app.use('/feed', feedRoute);
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Just a note, please add an Environment variable to check deployment type and if it's value is "Dev", only then you can add this check. Also you can try adding CORS related npm module - [cors npm module - whitelisting example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a proxy field to your `package.json` in your **React** folder:

```js
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

Then, make your requests like that:

```js
// this will also avoids CORS issues
const url = `/feed/posts`;
```

**Request Example:**

```js
// Create a state `Array` (or Object) that will hold all your posts
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  const getPosts = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/feed/post');
        const data = await response.json();
        setPosts(data)
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err); // failed to fetch
    }
  }
  // Make the request
  getPosts()

}, [/* no dependencies */])


return (
  // JSX use 'posts' here
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution provided by Legeo didn't work, but this more simple solution worked

```
const cors = require("cors")
app.use(cors())
```

or this modern

```
import cors from 'cors';
app.use(cors())
```